# How do use Xcode to list all files changed for a commit and see each file's changes?

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 4.3.  There are ways to see revision and diffs of a single file, but is there a way to see, for example, a commit yesterday at 3pm, for the list of files:

```
main.m  
House.m  
House.h
```

as well as the commit message, and clicking on each file will show the diffs for that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can get is to go to Organizer → Repositories → Expand commit (click ▶) and click "(View Changes)" button. That will let you see diffs file by file, but not whole commit at the same time.

Use [GitX](http://gitx.laullon.com/), it's much better at showing git history than Xcode — you'll see per-commit diffs, as well as merges and branches.

Both can operate on the same repository at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I think on my Xcode it is `File -> Source Control -> Repositories` and then I can expand the items to click on "View Changes"

Comment: In XCode 8, do Source Control -> History..., then select "Show X modified files" to see the files that changed for a given commit.

Comment: @DrewH it showing me only one file. how can i check all modified files